# MonoGame Mac installation instructions

Tags: c#, macos, xna, installation, monogame

Does anyone know how to install MonoGame on Mac. I have been looking around for a while and I can't find any guides. I have Mono and MonoDevelop up and running fine, but I cannot figure out how to install MonoGame. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general with MonoGame:

- Download the source code off GitHub
- Start a new project
- `Add Existing Project` for `MonoGame.YourPlatform.csproj` and `Lidgren.Network.YourPlatform.csproj`
- Add a reference to MonoGame with your new project

There really isn't anything to "install".

Comment: Is there any specific project type? It would odd to add monogame to a non-opengl project.

Comment: I would just use an empty project.  You basically call `game = new Game(); game.Run();` when your application starts up, speaking for iOS, `game` should be a member variable of your `AppDelegate`.

Comment: Thanks. When would you use the opengl project available for iOS after you install monotouch?

Comment: You would only use that if you were writing a game with only OpenGL and not MonoGame.  MonoGame is an open source project that exposes an API identical to XNA using OpenGL underneath.  You are going to save time using MonoGame, OpenGL is pretty complicated.

Comment: Oh alright. I had misinterpreted what the OpenGL application for iOS is. I thought that it might only expose the opengl apis necessary for monogame to run, not that it is only necessary when you are writing an opengl only project. Cool. OpenGL is complicated, but interesting :)

Comment: Brand new to MonoDevelop/MonoGame on iOS. How might we run the MonoGame samples? I get a whole slew of compile errors. I downloaded the ThirdParty dependencies etc. If you have answer, please answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11727185/monogame-samples-not-compiling-on-mountain-lion

Comment: These steps no longer work on Mac since there isn't even an mpack file availabe for Xamarin Studio for the MonoGame add-on. Also read that the former template would reference the Windows assembly instead, so it was necessary to remove the bad reference. Found these steps to be much more helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17008108/running-new-monogame-project-with-xamarin-studio

Comment: These days, I would just get MonoGame off NuGet, that is *much* easier. Just search "MonoGame" and install it.

Answer (score 0):

Just to update this post for modern (post MonoDevelop and `.SLN`,the new SDK structure) times.

The directions for VS Code and Apple Silicon are answered in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71417957/trying-to-install-monogame-for-mac-and-vs-code).

Only continue reading on Intel(x64) Macs.

For Visual Studio for Mac [setup](https://docs.monogame.net/articles/getting_started/1_setting_up_your_development_environment_macos.html) and [instructions](https://docs.monogame.net/articles/getting_started/2_creating_a_new_project_vsm.html):

Install [Visual Studio for Mac](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/mac/)

Install MonoGame extension for [Visual Studio for Mac](https://github.com/MonoGame/MonoGame/releases/download/v3.8/MonoDevelop.MonoGame_IDE_VisualStudioForMac_v3.8.0.1643-vsm8.0.mpack)

Since version 3.8, the packages are NuGet based; simply update the NuGet packages in the references for the latest version.

The new dotnet SDK structure with framework and X64 vs ARM(Apple Silicon) caveats are expanded upon in this [question].