# MonoGame Samples not compiling on Mountain Lion

Tags: monomac, monogame

So I installed MonoFramework, MonoDevelop and MonoMac and downloaded the latest version of MonoGame. I tried compiling the samples but they all fail with the same error
`Parsing error of #error Unknown platform`.

The problem seems to be that for some reason `#if MONOMAC` and `#elif MONOMAC` are being ignored.

If I remove the Windows, XBOX and Linux related code and get rid of the `#if MONOMAC` the code compiles and executes. Has there been a change and should I use something else instead of MONOMAC in my platform check (i tried with `__APPLE__` and `MAC` but neither worked).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to make a Mac OS app or iOS?  You mentioned iOS on my other question.

Answer (score 0):

It should just work. If you install the MonoGame templates, does it allow you to create MonoGame project for MacOS?

Comment: It doesn't work for any of the targets, not android, not touch, no MacOS. Even the samples don't work.