# Using Xamarin Studio and Monogame Application won't run

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin, monogame

I'm trying to set up my Xamarin Studio in conjunction with the Monogame framework and it seemed to work until I tried to actually build and run the default Monogame Mac Application Template. When I do so, the application starts to run and then crashes. There are no error messages, but there are the following warnings:

Warning: The referenced library 'System.dll' is not used from any code, skipping extraction of content resources.

Warning: The referenced library 'System.Xml.dll' is not used from any code, skipping extraction of content resources.

Warning: The referenced library 'System.Core.dll' is not used from any code, skipping extraction of content resources.

Warning: The referenced library 'System.Xml.Linq.dll' is not used from any code, skipping extraction of content resources.

Warning: The referenced library 'System.Drawing.dll' is not used from any code, skipping extraction of content resources.

Warning: The referenced library 'mscorlib.dll' is not used from any code, skipping extraction of content resources.

Any idea what's going on?

Also, a separate question, the book I'm reading is primarily for Windows user and says that I need to download the XNB builder which I don't think exists for Mac. The book also says that Mac users should be able to get through the book and often offers alternative programs and whatnot for them to use, but not for the XNB Builder. Do I need to get something else?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm no expert with cross-platform Monogame dev, but it strikes me as odd that there are references to several Windows .Net DLLs. What Monogame project did you create in Xamarin? And if I remember correctly the XNB builder is only useful if you're going to stick to the XNA/Monogame content pipeline (XNB being the 'content-package' file format) - personally I prefer to use my own content management system. However if you do want to use it, have a look at https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/game_development/cocossharp/content_pipeline/walkthrough/

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17008108/running-new-monogame-project-with-xamarin-studio

Comment: @Jacob Thank you for the direction. I looked at that other question and followed the instructions, but there's neither a Lidgren.Network.MacOS or MonoGame.Framework.MacOS file to be found in the folder I downloaded from the link they posted.

Comment: I believe this is the current project file (that post is from 2013). 
https://github.com/MonoGame/MonoGame/tree/develop/IDE/MonoDevelop/MonoDevelop.MonoGame.Mac

Comment: @Jacob Thanks for the help, but I think that's the same link as before. I have found both a MacOS folder and a Lidgren folder within the Monogame-develop folder, but neither of the files specified. Could the files be different since 2013?