# Trying to install MonoGame for mac and VS Code

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio-code, xna, monogame

I'm trying to install MonoGame for mac and VS code. I followed the instructions at https://docs.monogame.net/articles/getting_started/1_setting_up_your_development_environment_macos.html, but I am stuck at one place. I have the monogame editor .mpack file, but can't upload it to VS code for some reason. I did extensive research but can't find any answers. What should I do?

Comment: Visual Studio Code != Visual Studio

Comment: Perhaps try [this guide](https://www.reddit.com/r/monogame/comments/cst49i/the_ultimate_guide_to_getting_started_with/).

Comment: Sorry, I didn’t make the question clear enough. I understand VS code != Visual Studio, that’s why I’m asking this question. I just need to figure out why I can’t upload a .mpack extension that is on the Monogame Mac starterpack, and for some reason VS code won’t let me install it.

Comment: I might be wrong, but isn't .mpack a Visual Studio thing, not a Visual Studio Code thing?

Comment: Yep, you are right. I tried converting to a .vsix, doesn’t work on Mac. Thanks for trying to help though :)

Answer (score 0):

The "normal" Mac install instructions and files are only for use with Visual Studio.

### Install using CLI

Please note these instructions are designed for Intel Macs(x64), but **should** work on Apple Silicon devices(ARM) with `.Net6`.

You can roughly follow the [Linux install](https://docs.monogame.net/articles/getting_started/1_setting_up_your_development_environment_ubuntu.html) instructions.

1. Install [Dot Net Core 3.1 for the Mac](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/3.1). or [.Net6](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0)
2. Install [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/download).
3. You may need to reference this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29955500/code-not-working-in-command-line-for-visual-studio-code-on-osx-mac) on Terminal paths for `code`. Something similar may need to be done below for the `dotnet` command.

   a. Install the C# extensions: `code --install-extension ms-dotnettools.csharp`
4. (Optional) Install Mono. Required for some consoles and Android targets(Frameworks 4.5 and 4.7). See here for [compatability](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/compatibility/).
5. Open a terminal window. Run the following line, either the OS or from [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal):

```
dotnet new --install MonoGame.Templates.CSharp
```

The next two lines may be Linux specific so ignore any uncorrectable errors.

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-mgcb-editor
mgcb-editor --register
```

At this point, you should be able to create a [new CLI project folder from the templates](https://docs.monogame.net/articles/getting_started/2_creating_a_new_project_netcore.html):

```
cd /path/togame/parent
dotnet new mgdesktopgl -o MyGame
```

Open the folder in VS Code.

### Review the *projectname*.csproj file:

Note the `TargetFramework` line:
`<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>` or
`<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>`

Some targets require a different `TargetFramework`, like `net47` or `net45` as provided by Mono.

See [Microsoft's .Net versioning page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/selection) for more information.

---

A couple of additional helpful CLI commands to run from the folder with the `.proj` file; [Taken from this list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/):

`dotnet restore` Update all NuGet Packages

`dotnet clean` Remove all output files

`dotnet build` compile

`dotnet run` execute the program

Comment: Please let me know of any corrections I need to make, and the version of Mac you are running.

Comment: Preliminary reports, https://github.com/MonoGame/MonoGame/issues/7632 , suggest that the net6.0 versions of the nuget packages are available.